# Did Moses expect God to change his slow of speech as he spoke in Exodus 4:10?

Tags: exodus

Exodus 4:10
New International Version

> Moses said to the LORD, "Pardon your servant, Lord. I have never been eloquent, neither in the past **nor since you have spoken to your servant**. I am slow of speech and tongue."

Why did Moses point out "nor since you have spoken to your servant"? Did he expect God to change his slow of speech as he spoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The story of Moses in Ex 3 and 4 makes several things clear -

- Moses used his "slow speech" as an excuse to get out of doing God's appointed task
- Moses begged God to make his brother, Aaron, the spokesman for him.

Thus, I conclude that because Moses had a spokesman, he did not expect a miracle concerning is speech as he did not need to speak!

Answer (score 1):

We can only guess about this, for there is no Biblical answer provided. The point God made in response to Moses was that if Moses couldn't do the job, empowered by God, then God would not have commanded Him to do it. But notice how God worked with him anyway, supplying Joshy to speak for Moses.